# Buttons at corners of the screen

Tags: xml, android-layout, button

I need to place two buttons at the top left and top right corner. But I get the two buttons at the left corner. How do I correct the code? Please help.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/back_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:background="@drawable/new_back_button"
            android:contentDescription="@string/LeaveReq_back_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/logout_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/logout"
            android:contentDescription="@string/logout_button"
            android:gravity="right" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use LinearLayout as parent of the child view (Button) and want to have both button at two sided corner then update your code like below:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/back_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:contentDescription="LeaveReq_back_button" />
    <View android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/logout_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="logout_button"
        android:gravity="right" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If you allow to update parent with LinearLayout to RelativeLayout then you can update it like below:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/back_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/new_back_button"
    android:contentDescription="@string/LeaveReq_back_button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/logout_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/back_button"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/logout"
    android:contentDescription="@string/logout_button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now its up to you, how you can use it.

Enjoy Coding... :)

Answer (score 0):

With `LinearLayout`, views are placed next to each other depending on its orientation

You can use `RelativeLayout` with `align_parent` to achieve your layout

Here is an example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/back_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/new_back_button"
    android:contentDescription="@string/LeaveReq_back_button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/logout_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/back_button"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/logout"
    android:contentDescription="@string/logout_button" />
```